# PHPExcel : How to create new worksheet with template?

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpoffice

Currently using template excel sheet to add data, the requirement is add new sheet too, so need to add new sheet with same template.

My starts with new tamplate :

```
$filePath = public_path('Template.xls');
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($filePath);
```

Now, I have to create new sheet in same file with same tamplate without clone first sheet, because need to load fresh template without data.

Answer (score 3):

You don't simply want to create a new sheet, you want to copy a sheet with all its existing styleing

So create a clone of the existing sheet, give it a new title (because worksheet titles must be unique), and attach that clone to the workbook.

```
$newSheet = clone $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$newSheet->setTitle('Worksheet 2');
$objPHPExcel->addSheet($newSheet);
```

Comment: I should not clone from active sheet, because it copies from all entered data. I need a fresh template getting loaded. but condition is after fill first sheet.

Answer (score 1):

You've modified the question since I posted the answer to your original question.

If you need to create a new worksheet from the template ***after*** you've already loaded the original template and populated it with data, then you'll need to reload the template as a new PHPExcel object, and inject the worksheet from that into your original workbook:

```
$filePath = public_path('Template.xls');
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($filePath);
// fill with data
$template = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($filePath);
$newSheet = clone $template->getActiveSheet();
$objPHPExcel->addExternalSheet($newSheet);
```

the `addExternalSheet()` method ensures that all styles and structure (merged cells) are copied cleanly with the worksheet when it is added. Simply using the `addSheet()` method isn't guaranteed to copy that information correctly

Comment: Hope, my heading shows clearly that I need new template not a clone of filled data. i just added for explanation at bottom. nothing new I added in my question.

Comment: Well a template is generally without data; once you've added data to a template, it ceases to be a template